# For some reason Chrome did not write a file

Tags: php, laravel, browsershot

For some reason Chrome did not write a file at
In my laravel Project I had installed Browser shot using
composer require spatie/browsershot
and then

```
npm install -g puppeteer
```

```
npm install -g chromium
```

Also had set my paths

This is my Main Code In Controller

scenario 1

```
$html = view('result')->render();
        Browsershot::html($html)
            ->setNodeModulePath('"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\"')
            ->setNodeBinary('PATH %~dp0;%PATH%;')
            ->setNpmBinary('PATH %~dp0;%PATH%;')
            ->save(public_path('Rendered\shot.png'));
```

scenario 2

```
$html = view('result')->render();
        Browsershot::html($html)
            ->setNodeModulePath(base_path('node_modules/'))
            ->setNodeBinary('PATH %~dp0;%PATH%;')
            ->setNpmBinary('PATH %~dp0;%PATH%;')
            ->save(public_path('Rendered\shot.png'));
```

```
Yet Nothings work and i gets the same error.
```